# Sending data from html file to php and store in data base

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am sending data from html file to php but it is not saving all the values are storing empty in data base i think it is not getting values from html i am using following code

```
<html>
<body><form action="data.php" method="get">

<input type="text" name="$R1"  id="R1"  value="John"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R2"  id="R2"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R3"  id="R3"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R4"  id="R4"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R5"  id="R5"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R6"  id="R6"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R7"  id="R7"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R8"  id="R8"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R9"  id="R9"  value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R10" id="R10" value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="text" name="$R11" id="R11" value="thePassword"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form></body>
</html>
```

PHP Code For adding data into table it inserts only blank records.

```
     <?php

        $con =            
        mysql_connect("surveyipad.db.6420177.hostedresource.com","","");
     if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

      mysql_select_db("surveyipad", $con);

      $device_Id=$_GET['device_Id'];

      $R1=$_GET['R1'];
      $R2=$_GET['R2'];
      $R3=$_GET['R3'];
      $R4=$_GET['R4'];
      $R5=$_GET['R5'];
      $R6=$_GET['R6'];
  $R7=$_GET['R7'];
  $R8=$_GET['R8'];
     $R9=$_GET['R9'];
 $R10=$_GET['R10'];
 $R11=$_GET['R11'];

  echo($R1);


    $update_date_time=$_GET['update_date_time'];

    $teritory1=$_GET['teritory1'];


    $query=("INSERT INTO std     (device_Id,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,update_date_time,teritory1)

        VALUES 
 ('$device_Id','$R1','$R2','$R3','$R4','$R5','$R6','$R7','$R8','$R9','$R10','$R11','$update_date_time','$teritory1')");


   mysql_query($query,$con);
    printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name in

`<input type="text" name="$R1"  id="R1"  value="John"><br>`

to

`<input type="text" name="R1"  id="R1"  value="John"><br>`

`name="$R1"` to `name="R1"` and try

=> Make your query secure from sql injection.

=> Use `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$query=("INSERT INTO std       (device_Id,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,update_date_time,teritory1)
 VALUES 
 ('".mysql_real_escape_string($device_Id)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R1)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R2)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R3)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R4)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R5)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R6)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R7)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R8)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R9)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R10)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($R11)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($update_date_time)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($teritory1)."')");
```

=> mysql_* functions are deprected, use mysqli_* functions OR PDO

=> NOT IMPORTANT : It is better change `method="get"` to `method="POST"`, if you do not have specific reason for use `get`

Comment: any way that we may upload this php file to any server and access it from there in html file

Comment: Why do you want to do that?, keep both files in same server, I don't think you can access the file but you can submit the form action to server page.

Comment: thanks it worked instead of showing Record 1 inserted this can i show a alert that successfully added and it move to same html page

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attributes in your form should not start with `$`:

```
<input type="text" name="R1"  id="R1"  value="John">
```

...and so on

---

Your code is highly vulnerable to Injection.  You should update it to stop using [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and use properly parameterized statements via `PDO`/`mysqli`.

You are not sending `update_date_time` or `territory1` along with the rest of the form either.  Any reason to use GET over POST?  You should use POST for non-idempotent requests.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` from `name` attribute in your HTML. Change to `name="R1"`